# Many to many mapping with extra column persisting troubles

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

I have many-to-many mapping with extra column. Here some pieces of code with mapping.

GroupEntity

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "group", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<GroupBrigdeEntity> groupExchanges;
```

GroupBrigdeEntity

```
@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
private GroupEntity group;

@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "exchange_code")
private ExchangeEntity exchange;

@Column(name = "enabled")
private Boolean enabled;
```

ExchangeEntity

```
@Id
@Column(nullable = false)
private String code;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "exchange")
private Set<GroupBrigdeEntity> exchangeGroups;
```

My aim is to get group with given id and add some new exchanges to it. I do it this way:

```
GroupEntity groupEntity = groupRepository.findOne(groupExchangeSettings.getGroupId());
    for (GroupExchange exchange : groupExchangeSettings.getExchanges()) {
        GroupBridgeEntity groupBridge = new GroupExchangeBunchEntity();
        groupBridge.setEnabled(exchange.getEnabled());
        groupBridge.setExchange(exchangeRepository.findByCode(exchange.getExchangeCode()));
        groupBridge.setGroup(groupEntity);
        groupEntity.getGroupExchanges().add(groupExchangeBunch);
    }
    groupRepository.save(groupEntity);
```

When I run this code I get exception

```
2016-09-05 15:27:41.031  WARN 25232 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
2016-09-05 15:27:41.032 ERROR 25232 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'group_id' cannot be null
2016-09-05 15:27:41.033  INFO 25232 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2016-09-05 15:27:41.034  WARN 25232 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 1048, SQLState: 23000
2016-09-05 15:27:41.034  WARN 25232 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'group_id' cannot be null
2016-09-05 15:27:41.034  WARN 25232 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 1048, SQLState: 23000
2016-09-05 15:27:41.035  WARN 25232 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'exchange_code' cannot be null
2016-09-05 15:27:41.049 ERROR 25232 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'group_id' cannot be null
```

I guess that my GroupBrigdeEntity is not persisted properly because its properties are null on cascade persist. Can someone help me? P.S I hope you will excuse me for my bad English.

Comment: where is the IdClass of GroupBridgeEntity?

Comment: Here are all ids in my post. It doesn't have any another id @BillyFrost

Comment: If you have more than 1 `@Id` then you must have `@IdClass` on the class. Where is yours?

Comment: I don't have this one. I will read about it and will try @BillyFrost

Comment: @BillyFrost  tried it and it works! Thank you! But can you explain me what is the reason to use `@IdClass`? I will admit it as best answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an intermediate class there with multiple `@Id` annotations, hence the identity of the object needs to be defined by an `@IdClass` annotation. For a JPA provider to find an object of this class it needs to a single identity (PK) object that represents the object, hence this is why you need an id-class - the same thing would be passed in to `em.find` if you ever wanted to find it. This is in the JPA spec, and [JPA documentation](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/application_identity.html#PrimaryKey_Example_-_Multiple_Field).